# DateDiff function unexpectedly returning another date or a default

Tags: excel, vba, datediff

I'm trying to use the DateDiff function for a macro in excel using VBA.

To my understanding the code is supposed to return an integer value.

Here are the examples given online at this location: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

-DateDiff ("yyyy", #15/10/1998#, #22/11/2003#)  would return 5

-DateDiff ("m", #15/10/2003#, #22/11/2003#) would return 1

-DateDiff ("d", #15/10/2003#, #22/11/2003#) would return 38

Here is the code that I used:

```
Sub macrotest()

Dim dateNow, dateThen, dateFinal As Date

dateNow = Format(Sheet1.Cells(2, 2), "DD/MM/YY")
dateThen = Format(Sheet1.Cells(3, 2), "DD/MM/YY")
dateFinal = DateDiff("d", dateNow, dateThen)

Sheet1.Cells(5, 2) = dateFinal


End Sub
```

Lastly, This is what I had in my excel rows:

B2:  5/30/12

B3:  3/30/12

B5:  12:00:00 AM    (this cell was supposed to have the result listed).

-I got either dates that excel defaults to, or 12:00.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your dates in the excel file are actual dates or simple text strings?

Comment: Check what format cell B5 is currently set to.  Is it set to a numeric format?

Comment: No, they are formatted as dates in excel

Comment: Oops..stupid mistake, but still not fixed.

in cell B5 (where the answer was supposed to be listed) it was formatted as "custom" so I changed it to date, but the date that is listed in B5 is this:

1/0/1900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help system, DateDiff returns a **Long**.

Your code declares two Variants and one Date type. Instead of

`Dim dateNow, dateThen, dateFinal As Date`

you probably meant

`Dim dateNow As Date, dateThen As Date, dateFinal As Long`

This code worked for me. You may need to tweak it slightly to apply it to your particular situation (I used ActiveSheet to make the testing go faster)

```
Sub macrotest()

Dim dateNow As Date, dateThen As Date, dateFinal As Long

dateNow = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).value
dateThen = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).value
dateFinal = DateDiff("d", dateThen, dateNow)

ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2) = dateFinal

End Sub
```

Also I believe you have `dateNow` and `dateThen` reversed in your `DateDiff` function call.

Comment: +1 Exactly my thoughts which I was almost half way typing but discarded LOL

Comment: that worked! Also, you were right about the date variables being swapped. Thanks a lot mate!